# XSLT:How to deal with testing the value of an element?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file in which there is tag namely, <Gender/> It carries either 'M' or 'F' as data, now my work is to test the value and write `<Gender_Tag>Male</Gender_Tag>` or `<Gender_Tag>Female</Gender_Tag>` according to the values M or F respectively .. I tried this code .. It used to work in other circumstances..

Comment: Formatting suggestion: write your XML "as is", without using `&gt;` or `&lt`, then use markdown to format it as code.

Comment: Please use code blocks (inline or blockwise) for better readability

Comment: upvote for sharing pain of using XLST

Comment: I get simply a blank space introduced in that place ..
I mean the template MATCHES but not the CONDITION (??!!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All relative paths expressed in a template are evaluated against the current node. Your template match Gender elements, so *Gender='M'* returns true if there is any *Gender's* child named 'Gender' with the value 'M'. I guess this is not the case...

Use the dot to express the current node (here a Gender element):

```
<xsl:template match="root/details/Gender">
  <Gender_Tag>  
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=".='M'">
        <xsl:text>Male</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:text>Female</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </Gender_Tag>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: You may use two templates too

```
<xsl:template match="root/details/Gender[.='M']">
  <Gender_Tag>Male</Gender_Tag>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root/details/Gender[.='F']">
  <Gender_Tag>Female</Gender_Tag>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<xsl:template match="root/details/Gender">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space(text())='M'">
            <Gender_Tag>Male</Gender_Tag>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Gender_Tag>Female</Gender_Tag>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

My example differs in two points from Scoregraphic's:

1. It uses xsl:choose to ensure, that only one Gender_Tag element is created (that also means, that if the text is not 'M', it is always a Female)
2. Use of `normalize-space()` strips white space around the text content of the element.

Comment: `text()` can never be F and M in common, but the use of `<xsl:choose>` is fine

Answer (score 4):

Untested, but may work...

```
<xsl:template match="root/details/Gender">
  <xsl:if test="text()='M'">
    <Gender_Tag>Male</Gender_Tag>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="text()='F'">
    <Gender_Tag>Female</Gender_Tag>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Its not working .. am only getting a space introduced in that place .. if I try to test an attribute value .. I can easily do it .. but I don't know what is the problem with comparing the value of the element ..

Comment: You need to add a sample of the XML you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing XML its hard to be certain, but I think your sample XSLT should be:

```
<xsl:template match="root/details/Gender">    
   <xsl:if test=".='M'">
      <Gender_Tag><xsl:text>Male</xsl:text></Gender_Tag>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test=".='F'">
      <Gender_Tag><xsl:text>Female</xsl:text></Gender_Tag>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Use of choose as per another answer would be better (though I think it should be two explicit when clauses rather than a when and an otherwise)